# Is it possible to deploy OS X Applications for OS X Lion with XCode 7.x

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, osx-elcapitan

I'm running OS X El Capitan with XCode 7.3 and I need to develop an application with OS X 10.6 as the target platform. Obviously when using SWIFT I will have to chose at least OS X 10.9. How can I configure XCode to write apps for earlier versions of OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Swift code can only be deployed to Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) or later and iOS 7.0 or later. To develop for Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or earlier, you would need to code your application in Objective-C.

Comment: I know but how can I tell XCode 7.3 to create an Objective-C Project and deploy for 10.6

Comment: When creating a new project select `OS/X -> Applications` and then in the template list choose `Cocoa Application` and select next, on the next screen there is an option to select language which will default to `Swift`, clicking this drop down list you will see `Objective-C` select this as the language.

The deployment target can be selected within project settings, on the 'General' tab.